# How can I direct-login by using Google-Drive-SDK in JAVA?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to get users' access_token by using Google Drive SDK in JAVA.
I completed to get access_token when user log-in first time. But, I really want to direct-login. I know access_token be expired, so 'refreshToken' can be my solution. But refreshToken is always 'null'. How can I perform direct-login? Many advices welcome.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "direct login" When you requested the access token, did you specify "offline"?

Comment: @pinoyyid "direct login" means "user doesn't have to perform login process and user can login by token(I think refreshToken) when his access_token is expired..

Comment: "user can login by token". The user must login using conventional web mechanisms. I'll try to answer your question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate "login" from "access drive". Once your application has an access token for a given user/scope, it can access Drive on behalf of the user. There are two (main) ways your application can obtain an access token.

1. It can request access which will involve the user being logged in to grant access.
2. In step 1, it can request "offline" access, in which case it will be given an access token  **and** a refresh token. It can subsequently use the refresh token to request more access tokens without the user being present.

I suspect that you want to do option 2. This is described quite well at https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline

If you have tried this and you having problems, please paste your code **and** the http trace so we can look at the problem with you.